# GPUImageLookupFilter. Is it memory leak?

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, gpuimage

Could anybody explain to me how to clear the memory GPUImageAmatorkaFilter?

[image: my example GPUImageAmatorkaFilter]

If I close this controller, the memory is not cleared:

[image: leaks]

Updated:
[image: This result in IPhone5]

Comment: Try to test on device. I've found that the simulator keeps some memory, probably to simulate some texture cache.

Comment: I tested on a device, and I found some changes, but memory is not cleared.